# Math behind Keynesian Expenditure Multiplier

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, economics

Take a look at this page: http://wiki.ubc.ca/Keynesian_Multiplier 
Why can you find out the sum of the geometric series just by dividing the mps by 1?

Comment: I see no MPS, only MPC. Is that what you mean? And what is divided by 1? I can't see where that is. Can you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: ah sorry lol, MPS equals to 1 - MPC

Comment: @hejseb is there any other thing ambiguous in my question?

Comment: Oh, I see. I should probably have figured that out myself... See my answer below. Hope it clears some confusion up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the series
$$
1+r+r^2+r^3+\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k
$$
If $|r|<1$, then this is a geometric series whose sum is the well-known
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k=\frac{1}{1-r}.
$$
So if you have $MPC$ instead of $r$ and $MPS=1-MPC$, then this is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty MPC^k=\frac{1}{1-MPC}=\frac{1}{MPS}.
$$

Comment: So, it's just a well known geometric series then? What is the geometric series called? Ah, and would you mind giving me a link to more of these well known geometric series?

Comment: @MouseHello Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula where you have this result and also for a finite number of terms. It's not called anything in particular - it's simply called a geometric series.

Comment: Cool, thanks :)